# XSLT to pick specific ROW

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I have an XML like this.

```
<RECORDSET>
<ROW>  
 <INSTANCE_NAME>ABC</INSTANCE_NAME>
 <VALUE>12000</VALUE>  
</ROW>
 <ROW>
 <INSTANCE_NAME>DEF</INSTANCE_NAME>
 <VALUE>1500</VALUE>  
</ROW> 
</RECORDSET>
```

Pls help me writing XSLT to fetch value of VALUE tag where INSTANCE_NAME = 'DEF'.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you're looking for is called a *predicate* - to find the `ROW` elements that have an `INSTANCE_NAME` of `DEF` you can use

```
/RECORDSET/ROW[INSTANCE_NAME = 'DEF']
```

and so to extract their values you would use

```
/RECORDSET/ROW[INSTANCE_NAME = 'DEF']/VALUE
```

You can read the square brackets as "where" or "such that", i.e. find the RECORDSET element(s), then in each of them find the `ROW` element(s) *such that* `INSTANCE_NAME = 'DEF'`, and in each of those find the `VALUE` element(s).

Answer (score 1):

Selecting `VALUE` based on the `INSTANCE_NAME`

**XML**:

```
<RECORDSET>
<ROW>  
 <INSTANCE_NAME>ABC</INSTANCE_NAME>
 <VALUE>12000</VALUE>  
</ROW>
 <ROW>
 <INSTANCE_NAME>DEF</INSTANCE_NAME>
 <VALUE>1500</VALUE>  
</ROW> 
</RECORDSET>
```

**XSl:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
   <xsl:template match="RECORDSET">
      <xsl:value-of select="ROW[INSTANCE_NAME = 'DEF']/VALUE" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
1500
```